# Why do my Blender files automatically import to Unity

Tags: unity, blend-files

I am making a game in Unity, and I am using Blender to make the 3d models. However, whenever I save one of my 3d models, even when it is unfinished, it gets imported to Unity without me doing anything. Worst of all, when I delete the assets in the unity project it deletes the file entirely. I need a solution to this because my unity project is overflowing with models which some were just for learning purposes and were not actually for Unity. Thank you!